# Can anybody help me with Dimensions, RN?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm getting an error on device mobile8. What is correct width and height on iPhone 8?

```
export const win = Dimensions.get('window');
export const W = win.width;
export const H = win.height;
export const responsive = {
  mobile8: W > 342 && W < 375,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your aim on having an object with a key(mobile8) with a boolean value in this. Could you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to identify device width and height and make responsive css. Like, for example, if user entered from iPhone SE, I want to show this style: font-size: ${mobileSE ? W / 4.4 : mobile8 ? W / 3.8 : Error};

Comment: then that is the correct approach; what is your problem with this true false values ? Do you just want to learn what is the right dimensions of iphone8 ?

Comment: Yes, when Im entering from iphone8, its showing false but should show true if everything correct, and the problem is related with this part: W < 375

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

here is the pixel sizes all devices